# why the "capitalize" is not working in terminal

Tags: python

this is the code

```
mysk = ["python 50%", "c++ 20%", "html 0%", "js 0%"]

myskwithcounter = enumerate(mysk, 1)

for c, s in myskwithcounter :
    print(f"{c}) {s}".capitalize())
```

and this is the result.

```
1) python 50%
2) c++ 20%   
3) html 0%   
4) js 0%     
PS G:\test>
```

Comment: `capitalize` will _"upper case the first character in the sentence"._ In your case, what's the first character?

Comment: `.capitalize` makes the *first character of a string upper case* and the rest lower case. The first character in the string you are `.capitalize`ing is always a digit.

Comment: You probably meant `f"{c}) {s.capitalize()}")`

Answer (score 5):

`capitalize()` changes the first character of the string to uppercase. The first character is the number from the `c` variable, not the string from `s`.

Call `s.capitalize()` to capitalize the language.

```
print(f"{c}) {s.capitalize()}")
```

Answer (score 1):

`.capitalize` makes the first character to be upper case, in your case that is a number.

You can display the documentation for capitalize with `help(str.capitalize)`